# Is there a way to test every input?

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to test every input in a strategy?

So I have a strategy that i want to test every input and see how that affects its stats But I don't want to go and test every input manually
But rather use a Bot.

Example:
I want to test a strategy that has input to change the `EMA`'s length
So I want to test `EMA 50,51,52... 200` and see what `EMA` value can get the best winrate/profit

So the bot would test every input:
`EMA 50` = 50% profitable
`EMA 51` = 50.2% profitable
`EMA 52` = 49.9% profitable
etc...
And return the highest profitable input - in this example would be `EMA 51`

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to test is manually.